# Null Pointer Exeception on viewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a problem guyz whenever i run am trying to call `viewpager.setAdapter`,whenever i run my application it crashes.saying `MainActiviy.java:46`,and when i click the blue link on my log cat it takes me to the `viewpager.setAdapter` method i called. Below are my codes.

`MainActivity` class

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


  @Override 
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar);  

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

private static final String TAG_START_CAMERA = "Start Camera";
private static final String TAG_START_MUSIC = "Start Music";
private static final String TAG_START_USER_MENU = "Start User Menu";
private Toolbar toolbar;

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));***"This is the error line"***

  PagerSlidingTabStrip tabStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabStrip.setViewPager(viewPager); } }
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <include 
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />       

<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    app:pstsDividerColor="@color/colorPrimarySecondary"
    app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimarySecondary"
    app:pstsDeactivateIconColor="#66323232"
    app:pstsActivateIconColor="@color/colorPrimarySecondary"
    app:pstsTabSwitch="true"
    app:pstsIndicatorHeight="2dp"
    app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
    app:pstsUnderlineHeight="2dp"/>

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/pager"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="13dp" /> </RelativeLayout>
```

My `LogCat`

```
06-29 08:33:11.034  24717-24717/? E/AndroidRuntime:FATAL EXCEPTION:main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.lilstiikz.wehr/com.example.lilstiikz.wehr.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.lilstiikz.wehr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your MainActivity class is incomplete. There may have been a problem copying it - please edit your post and try again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `viewPager` is null, because `findViewById(R.id.pager)` returned null. The reason in turn for that is, as Harish said above, you set the wrong layout with `setContentView`.

In the future, you can debug a `NullPointerException` yourself by adding things like:

```
if(viewPager == null){ Log.e("MainActivity", "viewPager should not be null"); }
```

for anything you suspect might be causing the exception.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lilstiikz.wehr/com.example.lilstiikz.linkupps.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip cannot be cast to com.example.lilstiikz.wehr.tabs.PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: This is a different, unrelated problem - your original error is completely solved now.You'll get better results if you try at least a little bit to solve problems yourself rather than immediately asking the community for help.

Answer (score 0):

change `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar);`  to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Update :

For multiple page slider tab strip.

```
com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip tabStrip = (com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: did it sir my app crashed and it says       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lilstiikz.wehr/com.example.lilstiikz.wehr.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip cannot be cast to com.example.lilstiikz.wehr.tabs.PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: Seems like you have multiple PagerSlidingTabStrip. If you have multiple, use fully qualified name. Check the Edit.